# Trying to format the value of a function

Tags: python, function, formatting

I'm currently going through some of the study drills in a book I'm reading and the author wants us to try to run a function ten different ways. I'm currently at seven and am struggling with the eighth.

Mind you, I'm not entirely literate in terms of programming, but I'm trying to improve. Here's my problem.

```
function(arg1, arg2):
    print(f"I have {arg1} letters.")
    print(f"And I have {arg2} friends.")
    print("Wow, I need more friends...\n")

function('{} {}'.format(1, 2))
```

When I try to run this script it's telling me I'm missing a provisional argument (arg2); however, I thought I was including the proper syntax to successfully unpack these two arguments. Where am I going wrong?

I also tried calling two variables.

```
function(arg1, arg2):
    print(f"I have {arg1} letters.")
    print(f"And I have {arg2} friends.")
    print("Wow, I need more friends...\n")

argument1 = 1
argument2 = 2 

function('{} {}'.format(argument1, argument2))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can only think of 2 ways to call this function... how exactly do you get up to 10? (That's `function(1, 2)` and `function(*[1, 2])`)

Comment: You're calling the function with a single argument: the string `'1 2'` (the result of `'{} {}'.format(1, 2)`).

Comment: So does each brace need its own set of quotes?

Comment: @Aran-Fey We essentially just had to provide ten different ways to provide the values being called. I didn't choose to format them each time. The other ones just involved user input, providing the values, calling variables, etc. This book is meant for people new to programming, so I think it's just the author pushing us.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single string to `function`; it doesn't matter that that string has 2 values within it.  Nor does it matter if you use variables or constants (or even a mix of the two) to build that string; the same single string is passed to `function` either way.

I suppose you could `split` that string, but that seems a very roundabout way to pass 2 numbers.

Comment: So, I also tried to pass two different variables to the function. Since each variable is a different string, shouldn't that work?

Comment: Passing two arguments should "work"; not knowing what you wrote, I can't say more than that.

Comment: I realized I should have just included my original script, so I made the necessary edits.